# Multiple HTML5 Media Elements - Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I've multiple HTML5 video and sound elemente on my website. I've to use custom controls for the media so I implemented some javascript/jQuery.

With a single media, the control-section works fine! If I'm showing more than one single media on my site, the controls do not work anymore.

I think some javascript is overlapping. This is my Code:

```
var $controls = $( ".controls" );
var $playbutton = $( ".play-button" );
var $mutebutton = $( ".mute-button" );
var $timeline = $( ".time-line" );

$( $controls ).each(function( index ) {

    var $player = $( ".controls" ).prev();
    var player = $player.get(0);

    var $playbuttonsingle = $($playbutton);
    var playbuttonsingle = $playbutton.get(0);

    var $mutebuttonsingle = $($mutebutton);
    var mutebuttonsingle = $mutebutton.get(0);

    var $timelinesingle = $($timeline);
    var timelinesingle = $timeline.get(0);

    $($playbuttonsingle).click(function() {
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
            playbuttonsingle.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-pause'></i>";
            $( "#audio-background" ).addClass( "play" );
        } else {
            player.pause();
            playbuttonsingle.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-play'></i>";
            $( "#audio-background" ).removeClass( "play" );
        }
    });
    $($mutebuttonsingle).click(function() {
        if( $($player).prop('muted') ) {
            $($player).prop('muted', false);
            mutebuttonsingle.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-volume-up'></i>";
        } else {
            $($player).prop('muted', true);
            mutebuttonsingle.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-volume-off'></i>";
        }
    });

});
```

Is there any way to rebuild the script so I can use multiple media elements?

Comment: The problem is you're using the same ID `$( "#audio-background" ).addClass( "play" );` you need unique IDs for each player

Comment: You need to select elements with respect to your current element by using `$(this)` inside your code.